# What is the limit $a_{n+1}=\frac{1+c_n}{1+\frac{1}{b_n}}$ when n goes to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given that

$\left\{
\begin{matrix}
a_{n+1}=\frac{1+c_n}{1+\frac{1}{b_n}}\\
b_{n+1}=\frac{1+a_n}{1+\frac{1}{c_n}}\\
c_{n+1}=\frac{1+b_n}{1+\frac{1}{a_n}}\\
\end{matrix}
\right.
$
where $a_0b_0c_0=1$ and $a_0, b_0, c_0>0$
Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n$

My work:

- $a_nb_nc_n=1$, it can be proved by induction
- By checking the first 100 terms with excel,  $a_n, b_n$ and $c_n$ probably converge to $1$.
- The sequence is not monotonic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Convergence**

First I use the identity $a_nb_nc_n = 1$ and manipulate the first expression
$$ a_{n+1} = \frac{1+c_n}{1+ \frac1{b_n}} = \frac{1+c_n}{1+a_n c_n} $$

From here it is clear to see that if $a_n = 1$, then $a_{n+1} = 1$ and hence by induction the sequence $a_n$ converges to $1$. From here on we assume $a_n \ne 1$.

The equation can be rearranged into

$$c_n \left ( a_{n+1} a_n - 1 \right)  = 1 - a_{n+1} $$

From here, we use the facts that $c_n$ is positive (an easy induction shows this) and $a_n \ne 1$  to see that $ a_{n+1} a_n - 1 $ and $ a_{n+1} - 1$ have opposite  signs. Note that the equation implies that $a_{n+1} \ne 1$

In the case where $a_n <1$, we first note that if $a_{n+1} <1$ then we have a contradiction. Noting that $a_{n+1} \ne 1$ also holds we then have $a_{n+1} > 1$. As this holds we can then conclude that $ a_n a_{n+1} -1 <  0$ and hence that $a_{n+1} < \frac 1{a_n}$. From here we conclude that in this case

$$ a_{n+1} \in \left ( 1, \frac 1 {a_n} \right ) $$

In the second case where $a_n > 1$, a similar line of reasoning gives that that

$$ a_{n+1} \in \left (\frac 1 {a_n} ,  1 \right ) $$

Going again to the case where $a_n < 1$ we can iterate our result to find that

$$ a_{n+2} \in \left ( a_n, 1 \right ) $$

Similarly for $a_n > 1$ we have that

$$ a_{n+2} \in \left ( 1, a_n \right ) $$
This means that in this case where $a_0 > 1$,
the sequence $a_0, a_2, a_4, a_6, \ldots$ is strictly decreasing and bounded below by 1, and hence must converge.
Similarly in the case where $a_0 <1 $, the sequence $a_0, a_2, a_4, a_6, \ldots$ is strictly increasing and bounded above by 1, and hence must converge. We call this limit $A$. A similar analysis can be done with the sequence $a_1, a_3, a_5, a_7, \ldots$  We call the limit of this sequence $A'$. We can do the same analysis for $\{b_n\}$ and $\{c_n \}$ to get $B$, $B'$, $C$ and $C'$.

**Values**

At this point all we need to do is solve the system of equations (all of these can be found by taking the limit of all $c_n \left ( a_{n+1} a_n - 1 \right)  = 1 - a_{n+1} $ type relations)

$$ C(A'A - 1) = 1 - A' $$
$$ C'(A'A - 1) = 1 - A $$
$$ A(B'B - 1) = 1 - B'$$
$$ A'(B'B - 1) = 1 - B$$
$$ B(C'C - 1) = 1 - C'$$
$$ B'(C'C - 1) = 1 - C$$
$$ABC = 1$$
$$A'B'C' = 1$$

Multiplying the first, third and fifth equations together, and applying the seventh we get that

$$ (A'A - 1)(B'B - 1)(C'C - 1) = (1- A')(1-B')( 1 - C') $$

Multiplying the second, fourth and sixth equations together and applying the seventh we get that

$$ (A'A - 1)(B'B - 1)(C'C - 1) = (1- A)(1-B)( 1 - C) $$

Hence we have

$$ (1- A')(1-B')( 1 - C') = (1- A)(1-B)( 1 - C) $$

Recalling our earlier analysis, one of $A$ and $A'$ is $\ge 1$ (It was a decreasing sequence that approached the limit from above) and one was $\le 1$ (This is the increasing sequence that approached that limit from below)
The same holds for $B$ and $B'$ as well as $C$ and $C'$. Suppose now that none of $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $1$. Then the right hand side of the above equation is nonzero, and hence none of $A'$, $B'$ and $C'$ are $1$ either. But then both sides of the equation have opposite signs, and we have a contradiction. Hence one of $A$, $B$ and $C$ is $1$. Without any loss of generality we can suppose that it is $A$.

From here we can substitute $A= 1$ into the first equation to get

$$ C (A' - 1) = 1 - A' $$

Both sides have opposite signs unless $A' = 1$, hence $A' = 1$.

We can substitute this into the third and fourth equations to get

$$BB' -1 = 1 - B'$$
$$BB' -1 = 1 - B$$

Here we can immediately conclude that $B = B'$ and hence that $B^2 - 1 = 0$ and hence that $B = B' = 1$> We repeat this process to conclude that $C = C' = 1$

This gives us the expected values for the limits.

**An Edge Case**

If you have followed through this answer carefully you may have noticed that it does not cover the edge case where one of $a_0$, $b_0$ and $c_0$ is 1 and the other two aren't. Here we resolve this edge case. Suppose without generality that $a_0 = 0$ (and hence as discussed in the first section $a_n = 1$ for every $n$. We can than use the fact that $b_n c_n = 1$ to write the equation for $b_{n+1}$ as

$$b_{n+1} = \frac{ 2} {1 + b_n} = f(b_n)$$
where $f(x) = \frac 2{1+x}$.

Now note that $$b_0 \in (0, \infty)$$
$$b_1 \in f(0, \infty) = (0,2)$$
$$b_2 \in f(0,2) = \left (2, \frac 23 \right)$$
$$b_3 \in f \left (2, \frac 23 \right) = \left (\frac 23 , \frac 65 \right ) $$

The equation for $b_{n+1} can be rearranged to show that

$$|b_{n+1} - 1| = \frac{ |b_n - 1| }{1+b_n}$$

This shows that $|b_n - 1|$ is decreasing, and hence given our previous analysis for $n \ge 3$, $|b_n - 1| \le \frac 13$ and hence $1+ b_n \ge \frac 53 $. This means that for $n \ge 3$

$$|b_{n+1} - 1| \le \frac 35 |b_n - 1| $$

Hence, by induction
$$|b_{n+3} - 1 | \le \left (\frac 35 \right ) ^ n |b_3 - 1| $$

This shows that the limit of $\{b_n\}$ is 1. Since $c_n = \frac 1 {b_n}$, the limit of $\{c_n \}$ is also 1.

Comment: How $c_n$ is always positive ? Even $c_0$ can be negative.

Comment: Ah oops. For some reason I thought that $a_0$, $b_0$, and $c_0$ are all positive.

Comment: WIth negative numbers introduced into the mix there are significant problems with the sequence even being well defined. If at any point during the sequence any of the numbers becomes $-1$ the next step will have undefined numbers. Simply guaranteeing that none of $a_0$ ,$b_0$ and $c_0$ are not $-1$ doesn't do the trick either. setting them to $1$, $-3$, and $-\frac 13$, runs into the $-1$ issue on the second step.

Comment: Furthermore, when negative numbers are included, if there is a limit it doesn't need to be 1. The case where $a_0 = 1$, $b_0 = -2$ and $c_0 = - \frac 12$ is an example of this.

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake. a, b, c should be positive. I have edited my question.

Comment: This answer should be good then.

Answer (score 3):

The question is about the limiting behavior of the recursion
$$ a_{n+1}=\frac{1+c_n}{1+\frac{1}{b_n}}, \quad
b_{n+1}=\frac{1+a_n}{1+\frac{1}{c_n}}, \quad
c_{n+1}=\frac{1+b_n}{1+\frac{1}{a_n}} $$
with initial values such that $\,a_0b_0c_0 = 1.\,$
The first issue is that there are several divisions in the
recursion and, for simplicity, assume that none of them are
divisions by zero. Notice the invariant relation
$\, a_{n+1}b_{n+1}c_{n+1} = a_n b_n c_n.\,$ With the
initial value assumption this implies $\,a_n b_n c_n=1\,$
for all $\,n\,.$

Define the quantities (assuming $\,a_0\ne 1$)
$$ x_n := (-1/2)^n,\, q_1 = \frac{3(a_0-1)}{a_0+a_0b_0+1},\,
q_2 = \frac{3(a_0-1)(a_0+a_0b_0-2)}{(a_0+a_0b_0+1)^2}. $$
Verify by simple algebra and induction that
$$ a_n = 1+\frac{q_1^2 x_n}{q_1-q_2x_n},\,
b_n = 1+\frac{(3q_2-2q_1^2)x_n}{q_1 +(q_1^2-q_2)x_n},\,
c_n = \frac{q_1-q_2x_n}{q_1-(q_1^2-2q_2)x_n}. $$
Now $\,x_n\,$ converges to $0$ which implies that the
sequences $\,a_n,b_n,c_n\,$ converge to $1$.

The special case when $\,a_0=1\,$ is interesting. Define
the integer sequence $\,s_n := (1-(-2)^n)/3.\,$ Due to
the invariant relation, $\,c_0=1/b_0.\,$ In general,
$$ a_n = 1,\quad b_n = \frac{b_0-s_n(2+b_0)}{1-s_n(2+b_0)},
\quad c_n = 1/b_n $$ for all integer $\,n.\,$ Also, now
$\,b_n\,$ converges to $1$ which implies $\,c_n\,$ does
also.